Subdirectory library copies all includes into one dir upon install. How to include this dir when linking agains this lib?
I'm trying to vendor https://github.com/taglib/taglib in my project and link against it while keeping possibility to use this library installed in OS. The problem is that this library copies all header files into $PREFIX/include/taglib upon make install, and then you supposed to do #include <taglib/whatever.h> when linking against OS-provided lib.
But when I want to build the vendored version I do
 set(TAGLIB_DIR 3rdparty/taglib-2.0.2)
 add_subdirectory(${TAGLIB_DIR})
 target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE tag)
 target_include_directories(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${TAGLIB_DIR}/taglib ${TAGLIB_DIR}/taglib/ape ${TAGLIB_DIR}/taglib/mpeg ${TAGLIB_DIR}/taglib/mpeg/id3v2 ...etc all subdirs with headers)

Cannot just list all subdirectories where headers are located b/c then I have to reference them directly, like #include <id3v2.h> which is located in taglib/mpeg/id3v2/. Meanwhile, the same include for OS-wide library is #include <taglib/id3v2.h>.
Do I really need to do
#ifdef USE_SYSTEM_TAGLIB
  #include "taglib/fileref.h"
  #include "taglib/tag.h"
#else
  #include "fileref.h"
  #include "tag.h"
#endif

? b/c this is how I'm doing it in qmake now, and want to switch to cmake to get rid of this.
I'm new to cmake and feel like I'm missing something obvious, but it's kind of 2nd order unknown. Also, how exactly this library does this copying? Where is it specified to recursively find all headers and copy them into prefix/include?

You don't need target_include_directories. target_link_libraries does all the work.

@3CxEZiVlQ this doesn't work "fatal error: taglib/fileref.h: No such file or directory"

"this library copies all header files into $PREFIX/include/taglib upon make install, and then you supposed to do #include <taglib/whatever.h> when linking against OS-provided lib." - No, you are supposed to #include <whatever.h>, while using <PREFIX>/include/taglib as include directory (this directory is not included by default).

@Tsyvarev $PREFIX/include is the standard Linux include dir. For example libtag-devel in openSUSE contains /usr/include/taglib/ directory. If I want to use it I write #include <taglib/.... If you make install it'll copy headers into /usr/local/iclude/taglib. When you link against boost, for example, you write #include <boost/...> and it picks up boost's inludes from /usr/include/boost, you don't modify (unless you want to) includepath to be /usr/include/boost b/c /usr/include is already included, and you only refernce subdir in it

Different libraries use different policies about what should be #include-ed for use them. It is true that most libraries, if installed system-wide, works with default /usr/include directory. But there are exceptions, which requires non-default include directories. According to documentation, taglib is one of those exceptions.
